# Can "barge in" be used as an informal and quirky way of saying "come in" and "come on in"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, american-english, imperatives

I am looking for a specific US expression. An informal way of saying "all right, come on in" to a very good friend in a situations as follows:

1. The (drunk) friend who is barging into my <strike>suit</strike> suite unexpectedly, and asks me to let him enter.
2. The friend who is calling me around midnight to ask me to let him stay the night in my house.

Can I use "Barge in!" as an <strike>cool</strike> informal way of saying "come in"?

Example:

> 'Hi buddy, the girlfriend has kicked me out. May I stay at your place here tonight?'
>
> 'Hm... Well, you party bummer, barge in!'

#### Update 1

I'am looking for the exact English equivalent of Russian "заваливайся" (barge in), "вваливайся" (flock in), "проходи" (move on) or even more specifically "ладно, заваливайся", "ладно, проходи". I mean more rough, corky and informal equivalent of "come on in!", "move on!"...

#### Update 2

Thanks for your comments! I see the expressions like "get your ... in" and "get your ... over" can be used to reproduce the required meaning.

Comment: Whether you’re trying to be cool or not, _barge in_ usually implies that the entry is **unwelcome**, so I’d perhaps not use it with someone whose girlfriend has just kicked him out. It signals, “All right, if you absolutely must … but I’d much rather you didn’t”. (Also: a _suit_ is a set of clothing. I think you’re looking for _suite_, which is a set of rooms in a house, usually a hotel. Unless your friend really did force himself into your clothes, of course, in which case I can certainly understand why you’d wish to signal you’d rather he hadn’t.)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I meant to say "suite":-))))) Ha-ha-ha! Corrected the question!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, is there any expression with meaning of "ok, get your old freaky butt and bones in..." and tone of ridicule and sympathy at the same time.

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing the meaning with the informal ["Budge up"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/budge-up). It doesn't quite make sense in your context, but it is similar and has the informal tone you're looking for.

Comment: I can’t think of any expressions that refer specifically to coming in (i.e., entering the house from the outside). But you could say something like, “Yeah, all right, skedaddle on over” or something like that. If he really was just kicked out by his girlfriend, though, why would you _want_ to have a tone of ridicule in there at all?

Comment: There's (said with a tone of resignation), "Alright, get your sorry ass inside. You can sleep on the sofa."  (This would be said if your friend knocked on your door.)  If he called you on the phone it might be, "Alright.  Get your sorry ass over here..."

Comment: One person's cool is another person's not so cool. One person's cool now can be the same person's not so cool later on, when more sober. This should be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Drew, I have updated my question in accordance with your comment. Saying "cool" I meant "informal".

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer, IMO. Opinions about whether something is generally considered informal are more conventional than whether something is cool.

Comment: @Jim, thank you! This is very close to what i am looking for!

Comment: @Jim, thank you! These are really great expressions! I see the phrases like "get your sorry ass in (over)" are generally based on "get in" and "get over". What other verbs (besides "come" and "get") can be used with "in" and "over" to produce the same meaning? Can you please suggest me some other ingenious, rich and even sardonic alternatives?

Comment: Just as a note, I think you mean "quirky" not "corky."

Comment: @ChrisSunami, well, you are near right! I double checked with the dictionary and it seems that adjectives like "saucy", "flippant" and "pawky" are even more relevant.

Comment: 'pawky'? Is that some obscure British thing like 'twee' or 'chuffed'?

Comment: @Mitch _Pawky_ is BrE, but it's hardly obscure (as of course _chuffed_ and _twee_ are also not). It's probably less common than _chuffed_ and a bit more common than _twee_ (which at least I don't actually hear used very often), I'd hazard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more informal way of saying "Come in" is "Come on in".  In my experience, there is a clear distinction in when to use these terms.  "Come on in" implies that you know the person who is wanting to come in and that there is some familiarity with them, or you are trying to create an air of familiarity.  In a similar way, on the game show "The Price is Right", the host says "Come on down!" not "Come down here" or "Come here".

It may not make sense because there is only one word different, but usage defines meaning. Consider to the difference in "Okay" which means "Yes" and "That's okay" which means "No", at least to Americans.

As others have said "Barge in" could be used, but in addition to meaning "Come in", it would imply that the person was not particularly welcome or had a habit of intruding.  However, "Barge on in" would lessen that by adding the meaning that you didn't mind the intrusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for a really comprehensive answer! Now everything is clear to me. Your kind help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For your drunk friend, I'd say:

> Sure buddy, just stumble right in, if you think you can.

For your friend having domestic problems, I'd say:

> Sure buddy, plenty of room! I'll be staying with your EX.

And for a generic, good for all occasions greeting, I'd say:

> Sure buddy, just barge right in, why don't ya?

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine someone saying "barge on in" in the situation you describe.  It's not a common idiom, but it would be understood.  For some reason, "barge in" by itself doesn't sound as apt.

EDIT:  I'm taking it as a given that a playfully rude phrase is desired.  You wouldn't use this unless you actually wanted to be (humorously) rude.

Comment: _barge_ generally suggests either forceful or rude entry. So if you said this, it would likely be sarcastic.

Comment: @Barmar I think the desire for a sarcastic response is clearly implied in the OP's request.  He wants a playfully rude slang welcome for a close friend.  As such, "barge on in" fits the requirements.

Comment: Good point, then this definitely fits.

Comment: @ChrisSunami, thank you! You've got me absolutely right! Could you please suggest me a few alternative sarcastic expressions, maybe some common slang idioms?

Comment: I can't articulate why, but 'barge in' doesn't work well as an imperative.

Answer (score 0):

"Barge in" just sounds rude to me as though you want the person to know that they are unwanted but that your friendship will survive this intrusion. I might suggest something such as, "the keys under the mat" or "you know that you are always welcome."